# Parsing multiple values from a JSON Key

Tags: apex, json

So I have a JSON returned from a REST API call that looks like this:

```
  {"AccountId":"0014000001aasdfAA","email":"email1, email2, email3"}
```

What I want to do is parse it out so its normalized liked this:

```
 {"AccountId":"0014000001aasdfAA","email":"email1"}, 
 {"AccountId":"0014000001aasdfAA","email":"email2"},
 {"AccountId":"0014000001aasdfAA","email":"email3"},
```

I am not really finding an efficient way to accomplish this. Can anyone point me in the right direction with it? The goal is to turn this into a List of the contact object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `JSON.deserialiseUntyped` and get the values from it:

```
Map<String,Object> jsonMap = (Map<String,Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped('{"AccountId":"00128000009j45sAAA","email":"email1, email2, email3"}');
List<String> emailList = ((String)jsonMap.get('email')).split(',');
List<Contact> cons = new List<Contact>();
String accId = (String)jsonMap.get('AccountId');

for(String em : emailList) {
    cons.add(new Contact(AccountId=accId, Email=em.trim()));
}

System.debug('cons => '+cons);
```

**Note:** `0014000001aasdfAA` mentioned in your JSON is not a valid Id. You need to check that.

Comment: Oh I know that is just some gibberish, I did it intentionally there.

Comment: Using this method seems to return an invalid conversion error if the method type is List<Contact> what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

an alternative using custom apex types with deserialization support

```
class AccountWithEmails {
  Id AccountId;
  String email;
}

AccountWithEmails awe = 
  (AccountWithEmails) JSON.deserialize(myHttpResponse.getBody(),AccountWithEmails.class);
Contact[] contacts = new List<Contact>();
for (String email: awe.email.split(',') ){
   contacts.add(new Contact(AccountId = awe.AccountId, Email = email, LastName = ..));
}
insert contacts;
```